# Separate a column into many others in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe containg two columns, with country's names, and a value. I would now want that e.g. country "Italy" and all others, are columns, and than the values to be shown for each year under the country they belong to.

I want the dataframe to look like this:

|  | Italy | Spain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1246 | 64829 |
| 2021 | 230 | 11320 |

Instead, it looks like this:

|  | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITA-20 | Italy | 1246 |
| ITA-21 | Italy | 230 |
| SPA-20 | Spain | 64829 |
| SPA-21 | Spain | 11320 |

So, basically I want that instead of every country plus year to be only year written, and than the countries are written in the columns. I would be very happy if anyone could help me. Thank you a lot in advance! :)

Comment: try `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Country, values_from = Value)`

Comment: @AndS. thank you. Now the countries names are shown as I wanted, but the values are now in a row, and for each country as a combine function, that means I can not see them to which year the value belongs to. Do you have any idea for that?